# PDO Insertion is not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I don't know what have I done wrong. It isn't working.

I'm struck on this so long. I couldn't figure it out.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO hr_daily_claim(date,
                                 site,
                                 from,
                                 to,
                                 rental,
                                 vehicle,
                                 claim_id,
                                 parking,
                                 beverages,
                                 others) 

                          VALUES(:date,
                                 :site,
                                 :from,
                                 :to,
                                 :rental,
                                 :vehicle,
                                 :claim_id,
                                 :parking,
                                 :beverages,
                                 :others)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
                     ':date'     => $date, 
                     ':site'     => $site, 
                     ':from'     => $from, 
                     ':to'       => $to,
                     ':rental'   => $rental,
                     ':vehicle'  => $vehicle,
                     ':claim_id' => $cliamId,
                     ':parking'  => $parking,
                     ':beverages'=> $beverages,
                     ':others'   => $others    ));
```

Please someone help me.
It give me no error. But affected rows = 0; not inserting at all.

below is the table structure

```
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `claim_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rental` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vehicle` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parking` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `beverages` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `others` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`from`, `to` are [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You need to wrap it in backticks.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO hr_daily_claim(
                `date`,
                `site`,
                `from`,                //<-------- This
                `to`,                  //<-------- This
                `rental`, 
                `vehicle`,
                `claim_id`,
                `parking`,
                `beverages`,
                `others`
                        )
```

---

Sidenote: There might be a typo in the `$cliamId` variable in `':claim_id' => $cliamId,` which should probably read as `':claim_id' => $claimId,`, so do check for that, because those variables are not posted in your question.

If one fails, your entire query will fail. Another thing to note is that `$claimId` and `$claimid` are not the same. Variables are case-sensitive.

Comment: +1, nailed it. Perhaps you should also note that there IS an error actually reported by MySQL. It's only the OP's code not checking for it properly.

Comment: There might be a typo in `':claim_id' => $cliamId,` which should probably read as `':claim_id' => $claimId,` hard to say without seeing OP's full code.

Comment: Hmm fredd , Maybe his variable is itself `$cliamId` who knows ? :P

Comment: It could very well be. But again, hard to say for sure without seeing OP's full code. Should probably make a note of that in your answer Shankar. If one fails, they all fail ;-)

Answer (score 1):

write `from` and `to` words between quotes

```
`from`
`to`
```

just like in table structure code